# How to set language priority in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have set English, Traditional Chinese, Simplified Chinese in my app. Every time, I change my "language and region" to these three language, it will display the language what I Want.

But, if I change to other language which the app do not support (Japanese、German), it will display the language what I change last time like Tradition Chinese.

I would like to display "English" for other language which I do not support always!

I check my default language is "en", but the result is not what I want.

the images is my struct in Xcode

[image: info - Loclization]
[image: Localizable Strings and main storyboard]
 Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey you could take a look at Localization section here https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordered list of preferred localizations is provided by:
[Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1413220-preferredlocalizations)

You can reordering this list with 2 ways:

1. Programmatically (by settings  ["AppleLanguages"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html) in `UserDefaults`:
   `UserDefaults.standard.set(preferredLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")`
2. Manualy (in app settings):
   [image]